# Scattering with attractive potential

Tags: scattering, bose-einstein-condensate

In the context of low-energy scattering, as the potential becomes more and more attractive, the scattering length varies from negative, diverging then to positive values. It corresponds to wavefunction undergoing effective interaction from attractive ones to repulsive ones. I am confused by why deep attractive potentials will have equivalent effect as a hard sphere pushing the wavefunction outward (as suggested by the positive scattering length). Is there a qualitative explanation for this?

Additionally, since I read these when I am trying to understand BEC-BCS crossover, I am also confused by why the BEC limit correspond to positive scattering length. How to explain why diatomic molecules form with an effective repulsive interaction?

Answer (score 0):

All these general features of scattering with respect to extent and depth of an attractive potential can be discussed by the reflection and transmission coefficient at the 1-d potential pit.

For the long wave, low energy limit with free wave vector $k$ outside, the solution inside the pit is a small interval of the wavelength $1/k$ belonging to a free energy $\hbar k'^2 - \overline{|V(x)|} = \hbar k^2 $. The continuity conditions do not produce more than a little discontinuity of the derivatives, producing a non-zero reflection coefficient (fundamental difference wrt to classical sacttering effects in one dimension).

If depth or width of the pit reach the point where the free wave inside fits by half a wave length, things change dramatically, boundary conditions change phases and absolute values in such a way, that at each new knot of the free wave function inside, arising by deepening or widening the pit,  an abrupt change of the reflection (and, of course transmission) coefficient occurs with ever smaller intervals in external  wave number of the incident wave.

In terms of 3d scattering theory, the matrix elements of in and out waves interfere by geometry strongly with the bound states of the appropriate wave lengths as well as radial as orbital ones on the unit sphere.